# Undefined index-Undefined variable error PHP

Tags: php, variables

I've been given the task to remove undefined variable and undefined index errors, which i dont know how to

please some help

the code, problem undefined index is in the stars

```
                    $found_key = -1;
                    $found_key = array_search( $idc, array_column( $dbs, 'id' ) );
                    if ( $found_key > -1 ) {
                        $c_id    = $dbs[ $found_key ]['id'];
                        $daddy   = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Parent'];
                        $nameidc = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Name'];
                        $desc    = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Description'];
                        $tree    = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Tree'];  
                        $phase   = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Phase'];
                        $maindb  = $dbs[ $found_key ]['MainDB'];
                        $symb    = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Symbol'];
                        ***$o_id     = $dbs[ $found_key ]['DBOrder_id'];
                        $db      = $dbs[ $found_key ]['DB'];
                        $cid     = $dbs[ $found_key ]['CID'];
                        $nm      = $dbs[ $found_key ]['Calc1'];***

                    }
```

and the Undefined variable

```
                    <?php   }                       
                    $k = 0;
                    ***$ckt = array();***                   
                    if ( 1 == (int)$phase || null == $phase ) {
```

and

```
                        <?php if ( 3 == $phase ) : ?>
```

and an undefined offset

```
                    <?php 
                        if ( $gen[0]['gen_active'] == 1 ) {
                            $show = "block";
                            $check = "checked";
                            $link = "./index.php?workflow=update-generator-form&page=db&study=" . $tmpvalues[0]['Study'] . "&gid=" . $gen[0]['id']; 
                        } else {
                            $show = "none";
                            $check = "";
                            $link = "";
                        }
                    ?>
```

Comment: can you try like if ( $found_key  < 0 ) {  also check spellcheck in  = $dbs[ $found_key ]['DBOrder_id'];

Comment: no it doesnt work with < 0